# org.lwjgl.opengl.Display maximize current Window through code

Tags: java, lwjgl

My window is resizable and I can change its size using "maximize" button, but is it possible to do that automatically, through code? I need my window to have the size when I can see the taskbar and the top panel of window. I don't mean fullscreen mode.

I found Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height)), but I dont know how can I get the height I need, width I can get using

```
Display.getDesktopDisplayMode().getWidth()
```

. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found the solution (thank to @Martin Krajčírovič who found that 7 years ago), it's needed to do this:

public static Rectangle getMaximizedWindowRectangle() {
return GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
}

```
public static int getMaximizedWindowWidth() {return getMaximizedWindowRectangle().width;}

public static int getMaximizedWindowHeight() {return getMaximizedWindowRectangle().height;}

public static DisplayMode getMaximizedDisplayMode() {return new DisplayMode(getMaximizedWindowWidth(), getMaximizedWindowHeight());}
```

Comment: Assuming you are referring to a SO user and a post they wrote, can you link to the post you are referring to (Martin's post)? Please also link to their profile. See [how to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score 0):

Use `glfwMaximizeWindow` method in `GLFW` class.

Here is the [javadoc](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW.html#glfwMaximizeWindow(long)).

If you wish to have your window maximized at window creation, set `GLFW_MAXIMIZED` hint before creating window.

Comment: It didn't work. After I added that library to Gradle and invoked
'code'
GLFW.glfwMaximizeWindow(0);
'code'
ir crashed